# Variable in objective c

Tags: objective-c

True that this:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.goole.com"]];
```

But can I do this with the variables ?

How can I do this with the objective c codes with variables. Because Xcode gives continuous error.

```
int ebx, eax;
ebx = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
eax = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
[ebx openURL: eax];
```

Comment: Are you talking about [this Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)? I'm not sure what that has to do with anything. And, your question is unclear. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Could you make clear your question?

Comment: `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:@"http://www.google.com"];  `

Comment: And why you are using `int ebx` instead of `NSWorkspace *ebx; ` and  `int ebx` instead of `NSURL *eax`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to achieve this.

```
NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.it"];

[workspace openURL:url];
```

Anyway, do you know the differences about primitive and reference types? I really suggest to take a look at the basics of C Language and then Objective-C (passing through Oriented Object Programming theory).

References: [Objective-C Introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: @Max_RealQnx You're welcome. I really suggest to read the reference I provided.

Comment: I agree with you. However, this language is very difficult, and sometimes I can ask for help from you. Thank you for your understanding.